# onmouseover throws object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-9, onmouseover

`onmouseover` not working in IE9. The console throws this error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'onmouseover': object is null or undefined

Here's my code:

```
window.onload = function()
{
var FB;
FB = document.getElementById('facebook_logo');
FB.onmouseover=function(){FB.src='images/facebook.png';};
FB.onmouseout=function(){FB.src='images/facebook_mono.png';};
}
```

Here's the page in action.
[troythibodeaux.com/websites/mytappap/](http://troythibodeaux.com/websites/mytappap/)

The Facebook icon in the nav bar should switch when you hover over it, but in IE9 it is not working. Seems to work in IE7,8, Firefox, and Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error locally and found that it doesn't occur when the CSS file isn't included. I then found out which CSS rule is causing the problem. It's this rule for `#nav`:

```
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
```

I'm not sure why that's causing the problem, but it is. At least that was the case when I tested locally.

Comment: Adam, you are correct. Really strange why that would be causing it, but it is. The newest version of FF doesn't need -moz, but I wonder if the border radius will not show up in older versions of FF that use -moz?

Comment: @TroyThibodeaux `-moz-border-radius` is required for the border radius to work in versions of Firefox below 4.0.